# babelrc not sufficient to use with babel --watch

Tags: node.js, npm, babeljs

I have this .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": ["env"],
  "outDir":"target",
  "include":[
    "src/**/*.js"
  ],
  "ignore": []
}
```

I run `babel -w` and I get this error message:

> --watch requires --out-file or --out-dir. --watch requires filenames

do I need to specify more options at the command line or is there something I can add to my .babelrc file?

Comment: looks like "outDir" and "include" are not acceptable options in a .babelrc file - is there a way to configure this in .babelrc or must it be at the command line?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to configure this in your `.babelrc`. But you could add something like this to the `scripts` section of your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "watch": "babel --watch src --out-dir dist"
}
```

Then you can just run `npm run watch` from the root of that project.

If you want to execute your project each time you compile, you can use [babel-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-watch).